# Post with python doesn't return the after login page

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to login to a specific [game site](https://www.novaragnarok.com)  using python, this is my code:

```
import requests 
import webbrowser

s = requests.session()

url = "https://www.novaragnarok.com/"

myheaders = {'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36 OPR/64.0.3417.146'}

mydata = {'server':'NovaRO','username':'MyUsername','password':'MyPassword'}

r = s.post(url, data=mydata, headers=myheaders)
print(r.content)
```

Replacing `MyUsername` and `MyPassword` with my account doesn't return the page after Login, any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

First of all, you are sending the POST request to the wrong URL, try using this URL:

```
https://www.novaragnarok.com:443/?module=account&action=login&call=ajax
```

Secondly, I would recommend replacing your current headers with the following ones:

```
myheaders = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0",
    "Origin": "https://www.novaragnarok.com",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Referer": "https://www.novaragnarok.com/",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Yes! It works now!!! I completed my PriceCheck algorithm today because of your help. But one last thing, how you found the correct URL to send the request?

Comment: @MichelMarques glad to hear that! I found it using BurpSuite!